# Threejs r55 sprites doesn't display

Tags: three.js, sprite

I try to display a sprite with the r55 of three js version but there is nothing on the screen. Does anyone can help me finding the mistake please ? I'm not loading things locally to prevent some error. I don't understand why all 3d object work fine and not the texture or the sprites.
Thanks to all

```
var startTime   = Date.now();
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var camera, scene, renderer;
var ambientlight,directionallight;
var texturenuage, obj1;

init();         
animate();

function init() {

if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
scene = new THREE.Scene();

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, 901 / 727, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 0;
camera.position.z = 1000;

ambientlight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x220066);
scene.add( ambientlight );

directionallight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xff88aa );
directionallight.position.set( 40, 50, 100 ).normalize();
scene.add( directionallight );


texturenuage = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('nuage1.png');
obj1 = new THREE.Sprite( new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, map: texturenuage, alphaTest: 0.5 } ) )
sprite.scale.set( 381, 84, 1.0 )
sprite.position.set( 100, 100, 0 );
sprite.position.normalize();
scene.add( obj1 );

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.sortObjects = false;
renderer.setSize( 901, 727 );       
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );   
}

function animate() {
render();
requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}

function render() {
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't see anything because the textures can't be loaded if ran locally.

Use some of the suggestions in three's wiki page on running a local server and you might start seeing textures on the screen ;-)

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally